# How to add a new filter to MODX Minishop2 Orders

Tags: javascript, ajax, modx

How to add a new filter to MODX Minishop2 orders
Namely, filtering by orders from a certain restaurant chain of restaurants?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOWFn.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Next component will help you with new filters for minishop2 "Orders" tab: https://modstore.pro/packages/integration/msstatorders
There is only a Russian translation, please let me know if you need any help with  English version and understanding.

In general, this can be also achieved using custom plugins but unfortunately I have no good demo for you on my plate now.

Comment: I searched all over the internet and didn't even find a similar custom plugin.Maybe I'm looking in the wrong direction. Do you also not even have a free custom plugin like this?